# Did Delphi XE2 remove the IsWinNT function?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe2, virtualtreeview

Porting to XE2 and I've got a line `IsWinNT` that compiled in 7 and Delphi 2009 and never gave us any guff before.

I'm not sure what the purpose of such a function is, but was it removed or moved?

and what is a comparable function?

---

My bad, it was in Virtual Trees har. Sorry guys -1 for me. Free +1's on the house

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Delphi 2009, there is no `IsWinNT` function. In addition, there is no Windows API function named like that. Most likely you are confused: Perhaps `IsWinNT` was part of some 3rd-party library that you used?

Anyhow, if you are only targeting the Windows platform, then you can implement the function as

```
function IsWinNT: boolean;
begin
  result := true;
end;
```

since every Windows version since (and including) XP has been based on NT.

Comment: Windows 95, 98 and ME were all released after Windows NT 3.1

Comment: @Joe White: That is incorrect. Windows ME was released several months after Windows 2000 was released.

Comment: But 95,98 and ME were not based on NT technology.

Comment: @LURD that is indeed the case which makes Andreas's function a bit odd in my view. Maybe I'm missing some nuance.

Comment: Can executables compiled with Delphi 2009 even run on 98 or ME anymore, even with MSLU?

Comment: @David: I think that an application compiled with a modern version of Delphi (such as 2009, or XE) cannot be run on Windows 9x. Hence, `IsWinNT` should return `true` in every case where the function can be executed.

Comment: @andreas that's the official line but I have a hunch that if you eschew the vcl then you can still produce 9x apps but that's just nitpicking

Comment: @David: I just tried to run an empty standard VCL app and an empty console application made in Delphi 2009 under Windows 95 with IE4 installed. Neither worked.

Comment: @Andreas I can see why the VCL app would fail (Unicode APIs). Do you know why the console app failed? And how on earth did you get hold of win95 box??!!!

Comment: @David: [Two error messages](http://privat.rejbrand.se/w95ie4delphi2009.png) are displayed. (English: "The given device, path, or file could not be accessed." and "Error at application startup. The file %s requires a newer version of Windows. Upgrade Windows.") I have an old HP Vectra VE 200 with Windows 95, and, in addition, I have Windows 95 installed on my main computer inside VirtualBox.

Comment: @David, yeah, I didn't mark this as accepted for the wisdom of the function, which would certainly need some ifdefs if I want to cross compile with an older Delphi or anything like that, but he was dead on about isWinNT being part of a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know such function, but you can use this code

```
if Win32Platform = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT then
```

FYI Delphi XE2 only runs on WinNT based systems

Answer (score 3):

I can't find that function in any of my Delphi's (D6, D2010, DXE2). I would test for NT like this:

```
Win32Platform = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT
```

This test is a little redundant on XE2 since it no longer supports targetting non-NT versions of Windows. I've not actually tried running an XE2 produced executable on Win9x lately so I don't know whether or not it fails when you do so.

In XE2 you can now make use of [`TOSVersion`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.TOSVersion). For example, to check that you are running on Windows XP or up you would simply do:

```
if (TOSVersion.Platform=pfWindows) and (TOSVersion.Check(5, 1)) then
  ...
```

Comment: Yeah, the code was `IsWinNT := (Win32Platform and VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT) <> 0;`